# How to install modules through paver in python?

Tags: python, build, installation, pip, paver

When using paver for python build, how can I write a conditional for checking if my user has the required installed modules? If not then to be able to install it through the script. This should be written in pavement.py.

For an example, I am working with requests. When my user runs the build through paver, I want to be able to check to see if requests needs to be installed. It is like using pip, but in a paver script.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to import it and install in some other case:

```python
try:
    import dependency
except ImportError:
    sh("pip install dependency")
```